# Colored selected row in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to color a selected row from a dropdown list? jQuery/JavaScript is welcomed as well

Comment: yes... but if you don't show us some code, it will be quite hard to help...

Comment: It is just a simple select with preselected value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementById("mySelectBox");
var oldSelectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
select.addEventListener("change", function(){
    select.options[oldSelectedIndex].style.cssText = "";//or .className = ""
    select.options[oldSelectedIndex=select.selectedIndex].style.cssText = "color:red;";
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're also free to use the :selected pseudo-class in pure CSS.

Comment: What is the browser compatibility like for this pseudo class? I know :before & :after have varying levels of support, hence twitters bootstraps use of :before

Comment: Oops it's a jQuery thing and not really a part of CSS. Never mind.